# GeoJson properties does not display on Google Maps Activity Android

Tags: android, json, google-maps, geojson

I am currently coding a GeoJson layer and the marker displays fine, on the correct lat and long. Although, the properties that I add do not display if I click the marker.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": 
  [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": 
      {
        "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
        "marker-size": "medium",
        "marker-symbol": "",
        "title": "this is a test marker"
      },
      "geometry": 
      {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": 
        [
          -0.07659316062927246,
          51.50809472930477
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Above is a sample of the GeoJson code I am trying to use and the point appears in the correct place but it doesn't show the title when I click on the marker or any other way.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Does anyone have any idea? I can only use:

GeoJsonPointStyle pointStyle = layer.getDefaultPointStyle();
pointStyle.setDraggable(true);
pointStyle.setTitle(“Hello, World!”);
pointStyle.setSnippet(“I am a draggable marker”);

To get it to work but it then displays for every marker e.g. if I type hello world it will go to every marker, I only want it to display on one!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the ***infoWindow*** separately for each marker as java code even though you are coding a GeoJson.

Sample Code from official site:

```
static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                      .position(MELBOURNE)
                      .title("Melbourne"));
melbourne.showInfoWindow();
```

For customizing the info window, refer to this [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-infowindow-contents-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-infowindowadapter/).